# Link function names to codex

Tags: feature-request, formatting

It would be really easy if function names would automagically be linked to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference), [the function reference](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html) or [the Trac browser](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/). If someone could create a solution that does this via Javascript, we could probably convince *the powers that be* to add it here (if [Math Overflow can have MathJax to format formulas](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed), surely we can have something too!).

Comment: Cool feature, indeed.

Comment: I don't know if it should be automatic though, as could pick up false positives, but maybe some sort of tag to do it?

Comment: Well, we use backticks ` to mark code snippets ... maybe automatically highlight/link functions that are contained within backticks ... and use a tilda ~ or something similar to mark functions when they're used as a standalone references.

Comment: Great idea. Where are we on this?

Comment: @editor: Not very far! It would require someone to take up the work and write a Javascript implementation that does this. After some of us start using it (first as a Greasemonkey script), we can try to confirm the site owners to include it by default.

Answer (score 10):

Now that my [QueryPosts](http://queryposts.com/) ([meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/queryposts-com-lives)) WordPress code reference site had launched - in case connecting to Codex is complicated or not preferable... I will be very, verrrry open to provide such API to be used by WPSE. :)

Comment: Would it not be a problem that your site is not open source nor community driven like the actual codex ?

Comment: While nice in theory (and a very generous offer), I think, long-term, it would be preferable to connect directly to the Codex. Perhaps we could use queryposts.com as a temporary fix, and as a way to work out the script/API issues from WPSE's end?

Comment: I am just throwing this as one of the options. It's true that QueryPosts is _my_ site, but that also means that it will be more open and flexible towards working with WPSE than Codex. Anyway there had been little traction on this issue, so I am not sure if this ever happening anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I think it would be great if posters would include more links to the things they reference in-line with their questions. Makes the site much more useful. I feel like the WYSIWYG tool is pretty explicit, and I would prefer it NOT to add links if I don't want it to. Also, links are not allowed within a block of source code.

Maybe another thought would be to have named functions listed after the answer or question, like:

> Functions referenced in this answer:
>   **is_admin()**, **wp_enqueue_script()**

... with each one linked?

Comment: That's a nice format. I looked at the list of the function reference, and there are 3698 functions defined in WordPress, totaling 56308 characters. This should be doable in a single JS file. Who wants to give it a try?

Comment: I've almost finished doing it.

Comment: One small thing which I've just noticed is with `is_page` and `is_paged` - what should I do here? I'm regex'ing out the function names and so `is_page` is matching the function `is_paged()`

Comment: @Thomas, maybe try a backwards (lookbehind) regex?

Comment: @EAMann, I have a solution in my head, I just haven't found enough time to go through and change the current code yet.

Comment: @Thomas: Is your code public anywhere, so others can base their work on it?

Answer (score 4):

## We could start creating tags for functions and include the Codex Url in the tag wiki.

It would also give you a list of all questions about the function by <del>clicking</del> hovering over the tag.

#### Update:

I made a tag wiki edit for [query-posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-posts) Using the same format as Rarst's [queryposts.com](http://queryposts.com/function/query_posts/) format.

The Stack Exchange javascript already includes a regex parser for turning `[tag:some-tag]` into [some-tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-tag) so it shouldn't be impossible to add something similar using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/`tagged_function` as the url to output.  We would also have to convert `-` to `_` since our tags use a hyphen instead of an underscore.

Stack Exchange tag parsing regex function:

```
function(b, c, d, a, g, i) {
        for (var j = $(b).val(), p = sanitizeAndSplitTags(j, !0), s = !1, q = 0; q < p.length; q++)
            0 != $.trim(p[q]).length && ($©.children().each(function() {
                $(this).text() == p[q] && ($(this).fadeTo(500, 0.1).fadeTo(500, 1), s = !0)
            }), s || (j = $.URLEncode(p[q]), $©.append('<a id="' + p[q] + '" href="/questions/tagged/' + j + '" class="' + a + '" title="show questions tagged \'' + 
            p[q] + "'\">" + p[q] + "</a> "), e(d)), s = !1);
        $(b).val("");
        g && $(b).focus();
        i || f(d, $©.text());
        h()
    }
```

Comment: I would be against tags and manual maintenance of those for such purpose. **Codex** can't get close to complete function reference, we wouldn't be able to reach a fraction of Codex coverage in this fashion. The point of auto-linking is computers doing **all** grunt work. Getting human in the chain is compromise that shots the process (as it does for Codex in my opinion).

Comment: Have you ever looked at the [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) syntax highligher?  I was playing with over the weekend and created a WordPress language file that links every function to codex in the code block.  It uses a keyword parser that is slow with all WP functions in it but could be trimmed down.

Answer (score 4):

I have inquired about this in mod room and it was suggested as first step that easy to use endpoint would be strong requirement to consider this.

Function pages in Codex follow specific title

```
Function Reference/the content
```

and URL structure:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content
```

Since Codex is is powered by MediaWiki it exposes its API and it is possible to query for a page by title:

http://codex.wordpress.org/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&titles=Function_Reference/the_content

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
    <normalized>
      <n from="Function_Reference/the_content" to="Function Reference/the content" />
    </normalized>
    <pages>
      <page pageid="765" ns="0" title="Function Reference/the content" touched="2012-01-03T22:52:29Z" lastrevid="110295" counter="18814" length="4259" fullurl="http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content" editurl="http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference/the_content&amp;action=edit" />
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

If page is missing:

http://codex.wordpress.org/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&titles=not_a_function

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
    <normalized>
      <n from="not_a_function" to="not a function" />
    </normalized>
    <pages>
      <page ns="0" title="not a function" missing="" fullurl="http://codex.wordpress.org/not_a_function" editurl="http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=not_a_function&amp;action=edit" />
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

Response format can be customized, as well as other properties. I am not very proficient with it, just put this together from [API docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/api.php).

Comment: Just dropping a note that this is still being investigated. Sorry for the delays. ♪

Answer (score 1):

I'm tagging this as a favorite so I can quickly get back to this URL via meta:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L775

Or more generally:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/<version>/<file path>#<line no.>