# Links to Codex pages

Tags: feature-request

This is a similar request to [this question](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/link-function-names-to-codex), (which suggests a feature which would be just as useful).

When questions/answers are linked to, it appears on the right side-bar under a title 'linked'. I would quite like to see another section (or perhaps merged with the 'linked' section) which includes Codex pages that are linked to as well.

This would provide a quick reference to related Codex pages and, I think, would be useful to those with similar questions as well the OP. (And it wouldn't prove too difficult to implement :D.)

Comment: Just to make a comment here and bring it back on top: Yes, where's this parser? :)