# QueryPosts.com lives

Tags: discussion

Long long time ago, on a meta right here - [there were ideas about custom domain](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be) for the WPSE. Then the whole custom domain thing was scrapped and for that long time leading domain choice of queryposts.com had been registered by SE and gathering dust in limbo.

It was still on my mind and just recently things happened:

1. I got an idea for a WP site that community might like and I will have a blast developing.
2. I finally hit upon right people in SE higher powers and they transferred domain to me to use for this project. Thank you!

And just like that earlier today **[teaser page for QueryPosts.com](http://queryposts.com/)** went live.

So I am going to do my best on this (as fast as life allows) and hope WP community at large and awesome part of it that is WPSE will find it likeable and worthy of the domain that might not happened without them.

Wish me luck? :)

http://queryposts.com/ **[update] now live!**

Comment: Good luck!!!!!!

Comment: Same from me. Btw: `em` should be at least `#bbb` :)

Comment: @kaiser ems are sneaky intentionally :)

Comment: I hope there is going to be a full page dedicated to not using `query_posts()`

Comment: @Brady there will be plenty of such, but not on this site :) look out for Happy Loops

Comment: @Rarst - http://www.wallpaper4me.com/images/wallpapers/happy_fruit_loops_w1.jpeg

Comment: By the way, this announcement would be ideal for the (AFAIK) still-non-existent WPSE blog...

Comment: @Chip yes... I thought long and hard about that blog and at moment I just don't have honest capacity to work on it :(

Comment: I think there are enough of us around here with some interesting knowledge that could possibly make the blog work, I heard WordPress supports multiple authors too!

Comment: @wYCK Speak it out loud in chat :)

Comment: Rarst, you sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Nice useful resource, bookmarked into my Wordpress folder alongside WPSE, haha.

Comment: Great resource there, thanks

Comment: Good luck; but I wish me a bundle form wpseek.com and your queryposts.com ;)

Comment: I'm closing this question because the site in the question has gone offline.